# Do the new DLC items count towards the collection achievements?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Some months ago, Ashes of Ariandel released as DLC for Dark Souls 3 adding in many items including 4 new spells and 1 new ring. However, DS3 already had achievements for collecting all spells and all rings.

Do these new items affect the achievements so that I will have to gather the DLC items as well as the already existing items in order to get the achievement?

Comment: If the achievement was released before the DLC, then the DLC items do not count toward the achievement. It should say next to the achievement whether or not it is a DLC achievement.

Comment: *Usually* (except for some [terrible cases](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/564ktm/achievements_from_a_game_dlc_should_only_appear/)) Achievements/Trophies will only apply to the vanilla game, and DLC achievements are often marked as DLC (Usually like "Darks Souls - [DLC pack] for Xbox, or with a '+' for Playstation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is usually not the case.

If there are DLC-specific trophies/achievements, they will be listed in a separate list. However, Bloodborne has been the only Souls-related title to have DLC trophies, and even then, involved a *DLC-specific* collection trophy or two, rather than changing the requirements for the base game's collection trophies.

Thus, it's definitely safe to say that you will be able to get the 100% collection trophies/achievements without having to collect everything from Ashes of Ariandel (or the next DLC).

Answer (score -2):

I have all the sorceries, except the new ones from the DLC. I have checked many times to make sure I have them all and I do, yet I still have no achievement. This proves that the new sorceries affect achievements.

Comment: Are you sure? Everything I'm reading online indicates the DLC rings/sorceries/pyromancies/miracles don't affect the trophies/achievements.

Comment: Don't place a comment or reaction as an answer. Just react to venomus post